# How do I manipulate the digits of a number?

Tags: c

In some kinds of problems I often face this situation where I have a variable where I need to rearrange the digits, e.g., `int e = 2385;`. Let's suppose I don't know which number is stored there, but still I need to shift 2nd and 4th position. When I know variable's value I can simply do `e = 2583`, but when I don't know I simply can't solve the problem.

Another situation is when I have two values and want to use them to form another number i.e `int a = 2, b = 1;`, and I need to order them so that I will get a 21 or a 212. I mean, that's easy to do when I'm outputting data, I can simply do:

```
printf("%d%d\n",a,b); 
printf("%d%d%d",a,b,a);
```

Problem is when I have to store this number in another variable. I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I'm sure you could use powers of ten to get the digits. 1234/1000 = 1 and so on. e.g to get the second you would 1234-1000 = 234 so 234/100 = 2, then 234-2*100 = 34 so 34/10 = 3

Comment: "In some kinds of problems I often face this situation where I have a determined variable where I need to shift digits position i.e int e = 2385" - what kinds of programs?

Comment: From where do you start to count the position left or right?

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz from left.
@MitchWheat get a palindrome, subtract 1, then invert the last and first digits. On four digits numbers that means same as subtracting 1000. But what if I have a bigger number, but I don't know it's size? 
What I mean is that I would like to treat each digit separately, if possible. 
Now, on a different case, I also need to put numbers together to create another, like in the example of variables `a` and `b` I gave above. This will turn very handy to work on the remainders in a long division calculator that shows the calculation just as we do by hand, for example.

Comment: @MitchWheatby the way the problems where proposed by my teacher, so they're not for serious/commercial programming WHEN we're talking about inverting digits position. But on the second case, I really wanna construct a bunch of calculators that print the math just as we do in paper, and I didn't figure out all of them yet, but for the long division (with and without decimals) I indeed think having a way to get i.e `int a = 1` and `int b = 2` and putting them together as algarisms of a third number is going to be useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be broken into two tasks: (1) breaking up a number into pieces, and (2) combining pieces into a whole number.

1. To break up a number into pieces, use the division and modulus operators.

   ```
   int num = 2385;

   int a = num / 1000;       // 2
   int b = num / 100 % 10;   // 3
   int c = num / 10  % 10;   // 8
   int d = num / 1   % 10;   // 5
   ```

   The trick is to use division to remove the digits to the right, then modulus to keep only the rightmost digit. For example, to calculate the hundreds' place (`b`) we compute 2385 / 100, which is 23. 23 % 10 is the remainder when you divide 23 by 10. The remainder is 3.
2. To combine the pieces back into a number, do the opposite with multiplication and addition.

   ```
   num = a * 1000            //   2000
       + d *  100            // +  500
       + c *   10            // +   80
       + b *    1;           // +    3
                             //   ----
                             //   2583
   ```

   Notice how I switched `d` and `b` to swap those digits.